# Relative path of Cpack installed application (windows)

Tags: c++, cpack

I have an application that need to access some files in a folder located inside the application directory.

```
myAppDir
   |-bin/myApp.exe
   |-scripts/need_to_find_this_file.py
```

I can't use `configure_file(...)` or other hardcoding method because they are processed at cmake-time.

I can't even have access to the installation directory choosen by the user because not an information that can be accessed by cpack.

How could I retrieve the path `~/myAppDir/scripts` at the run-time? I want to use it inside my c++ code.